# Android 13 phone dialer pad issue

Tags: android

On My Android 13 real device I can't open the phone dialer from my app ? is their any specific permissions I need to add apart from

I added the above two permission and I tried but still same problem.So please help me on this.

Comment: Specified method is not supported alert message its showing instead of phone dialer.

Comment: fbsEx {Xamarin.Essentials.FeatureNotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.   at Xamarin.Essentials.Email.ComposeAsync (Xamarin.Essentials.EmailMessage message) [0x00007] in D:\a\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Essentials\Email\Email.shared.cs:19    at NavistarOCCAp…}

Comment: fnse {Xamarin.Essentials.FeatureNotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.   at Xamarin.Essentials.PhoneDialer.ValidateOpen (System.String number) [0x0001a] in D:\a\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Essentials\PhoneDialer\PhoneDialer.shared.cs:13    at Xamarin.Essent…}